# Drupal node add/edit form - text input fields in a table

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

Is there a Drupal 7 module out there than can arrange text input fields into a table format on the node add/edit form?

Field collection module is not suitable as although it does have a table formatter it's purpose is to allow the user to add rows of data to the table themselves.

What I need is several text input fields just arranged into rows and columns on the node add/edit form - the user user should not be able to add or remove rows or columns.

Tablefield module is also not suitable as again it allows the user to construct the table themselves.

I have an image which perfectly demonstrates what I need, but I am unable to post images as I don't enough reputation points.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you say

> "Tablefield module is also not suitable as again it allows the user to
>   construct the table themselves."

While adding fields to your content type, in the field settings you can **restrict** the **"Table rebuild"**

[image: This is the field settings snapshot]

OR

You can also **restrict** the table entry modification based on people **Roles** and **Permissions**. Below is the snapshot of permission page.

[image: This is the permission page snapshot]